# Android does not load the secondary ABI on a similar app

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

We have two identical apps. They both have the same project structure. There are native shared libraries (compiled, no access to source code). I have placed the shared libraries in,

1. `root/app/main/jniLibs/armeabi`
2. `root/app/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` and
3. `root/app/main/jniLibs/x86`

There's no `.so`  file targeting the `arm64` architecture.

My device supports the following architectures,

```
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [arm64-v8a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: [arm64-v8a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
```

However, the first app runs without any issues but the second one crashes with a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. Following is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.someapp.name-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.someapp.name-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libstar_wars_jni.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
    at com.native.library.tstlib.<clinit>(tstlib.java:6)
    at com.someapp.name.FingerprintDevice$1.disconnect(FingerprintDevice.java:82)
    at com.someapp.name.FingerprintDevice$1.onReceive(FingerprintDevice.java:73)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

I have also inspected the generated APK and found that the `so` files exist in the apk's `/lib` directory.

I am not sure where to look next. Pointers are appreciated :)

Comment: I didn't get several things. You said, there's no `arm64-v8a` library, but then you say, there's some library in folder `lib`, you also say nothing about folder `lib64`, where application searches for you library. And what's your device architecture?